# php not receiving ajax data

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, post

Here's my java script code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
var getOption = $("input:radio[name='profit']");
getOption.click(function(){
if (this.value == 'amount') {
    $('.graph_per').hide();
    $('.graph_amt').show(); 
    }
else if(this.value == 'percentage') {
    $('.graph_amt').hide();
    $('.graph_per').show(); 
    }           
    });
    var get="";
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'localhost/testp/admin.php', 
    data: {get:"amount"},
    success: function( response )    {
       console.log( response );
    }
 });
});
```

when i post the get variable in php it shows the error : undefined index 'get'. how can fix it  & my this js file is stored in different folder .
 the php file

```
<?php
echo $_POST["get"];
?>
```

Comment: it's a post variable, use print_r($_POST);

Comment: Show ur php Code of $_POST

Comment: Provide more details. More javascripts and/or PHP code.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
var getOption = $("input:radio[name='profit']");
getOption.click(function(){
if (this.value == 'amount') {
 $('.graph_per').hide();
 $('.graph_amt').show(); 
 }
else if(this.value == 'percentage') {
 $('.graph_amt').hide();
 $('.graph_per').show(); 
 }   
 });
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'admin.php', 
    data: {var get="amount"},
    success: function( response ) {
       console.log( response );
    }
 });
});

Comment: Please, [edit your current question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14108469/edit)

Comment: Show the PHP code that's getting the error.

Comment: What `var get` should have?

Comment: Why did you change `get:` to `get=` in the AJAX call? Which is in the actual code?

Comment: do you get any error in the firebug console.?/

Comment: Why are you updating your code? Post only the original code, not suggestions made here.

Comment: If you go into the Network tab of Developer Tools/Firebug, what does it say it's sending in this AJAX request?

Answer (score 1):

Following is the tested correct code:-

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'admin.php', 
    data: { get: "amount" },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
    }
});
```

Problem is the path of the file "admin.php". If "admin.php" and the JS file are in the same folder, then above code is fine.
If admin.php is outside the folder in which your js file is, then change "admin.php" to "../admin.php". Here "../" is for one directory level back of the current folder. Change it accordingly if "admin.php" is two or three level back of the folder, in which your JS file is.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'admin.php', 
    data: { "get": "amount" },
    success: function( response ) {
       console.log( response );
    }
 });
```

PHP

```
echo $_POST["get"];
```

From the code you added as comment, i see that you are doing:

```
..
 data: {get="amount"}
..
```

so change that to

```
 data: {"get" : "amount"}
```

Comment: try using full url for "admin.php" in your ajax, like http://localhost/yourproject/admin.php ..

Comment: The server script is running, since it's reporting an error. How could changing the URL fix that?

Comment: In JS objects there's no difference between `{ "foo": "bar" }` and `{ foo: "bar" }` unless `foo` is a JS keyword.

Comment: ive tried this  data: {"get" : "amount"} , no improvements yet

Comment: No, `get` is not a JS keyword, there's no need to quote it. Actually, I don't think keywords need to be quoted, either, just anything that isn't a simple token, e.g. if it contains punctuation characters.

Comment: @Barmar From question, `get` is a variable, so, in this case is the same to send `'' : 'amount'` as data, because `get` is `''` (empty)

Comment: since get is assigned empty value, so doing get : "amount" would be sending empty index, so either do { "get" : "amount" } or change it to { "amount" : get } ...

Comment: nothing working , is there any other way i can get javascript variable values in php

Comment: any chance of unsetting the incoming GET/POST variables in the server side? because above code must work.

Comment: @USER1477731, from your php code try doing echo "<pre>"; print_r($_REQUEST); echo "</pre>"; exit; and see what you get in console...

Comment: @Barmar yes you're right, there's no difference between { "foo": "bar" } and { foo: "bar" }, but it's better to avoid direct `foo`, and use `"foo"` instead without fear if it's js keyword. This is just what good "design" does dictate

Comment: @metal_fan It's not common Javascript style, and even if you recommend it, it's still not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({  
    type: 'POST',  
    url: 'localhost/testp/admin.php', 
    data: { get: "amount" },
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
    }
});
```

Check the URL path.